# Function to clone buffer, narrow it and rename it to the name of the current heading

Tags: org-mode, functions

I would like to go to an org heading `* [A] HeadingTitle :sometag:`, then clone a buffer, rename it to "HeadingTitle" and narrow it to this heading - all in one function.

I know how to add the cloning and narrowing. But how do I get the name of the current heading and pass it to the `rename-buffer` function?

Comment: This doesn't answer the part about naming for an Org heading. But you might also be interested in it: library [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components of the current heading can be obtained using `(org-heading-components)`. In particular, the headline text itself can be obtained with `(nth 4 (org-heading-components))`. However, you might have to sanitize it (e.g. delete or replace characters that would be problematic in a filename if you decide to save the cloned buffer into a file).

Comment: I tried `(defun my/clone-rename-narrow (&optional arg)   (interactive "P")
   (clone-indirect-buffer (nth 4 (org-heading-components)) t nil)
   (other-window)
   (org-narrow-to-subtree)
  )` but it does not work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Lose the `other-window` call. Strictly speaking that was a different question and you should ask it separately: questions and answers in comments are not searchable and therefore useless from the point of view of future visitors.

Comment: Okay, I posted the question here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71590/function-to-clone-and-rename-buffer-and-narrow-to-subtree . It works without `other-window`, but the title gets passed with the task count `[0/0]`

Comment: I meant it more as good practice to follow in the future, but I appreciate the effort you went to to create the question (which I answered there but without much detail - I'll probably edit later to explain). As for the task count, you can try a new question: I don't have a quick answer. As another suggestion for the future however, make sure that you add all that you want in your original question (but once that question gets answered, do *NOT* change it: ask a different question instead).