# Function to clone and rename buffer and narrow to subtree

Tags: org-mode, functions

This is a continuation of [another question of mine](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/function-to-clone-buffer-narrow-it-and-rename-it-to-the-name-of-the-current-hea) which stated:

> I would like to go to an org heading * [A] HeadingTitle :sometag:, then clone a buffer, rename it to "HeadingTitle" and narrow it to this heading - all in one function.

I tried

```
(defun my/clone-rename-narrow (&optional arg)   
 (interactive "P")
 (clone-indirect-buffer (nth 4 (org-heading-components)) t nil)
 (other-window)
 (org-narrow-to-subtree)
)
```

but it does not work. What do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: I actually answered this question in a comment to your other question, although I did mention there  that it's not a good idea to ask questions in comments.

Comment: What's the question? What does "does not work" mean? The question isn't clear.

Comment: I fixed up the question a bit (with the benefit of prior context), but as @Drew  points out, the question has to stand on its own: it has to have a complete description of the problem and It has to *be* a question, not just a statement of what happened (although a complete statement of what happened is often a necessary *part* of the question - in particular, "does not work" is never a good description of what happened: describe the error in detail and include error messages verbatim). Read a  guide on how to ask a good question, e.g. [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @NickD !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```el
(defun my/clone-rename-narrow (&optional arg)   
 (interactive "P")
 (clone-indirect-buffer (nth 4 (org-heading-components)) t nil)
 (org-narrow-to-subtree)
)
```

without the `other-window` call.

If you look at the doc string for `clone-indirect-buffer` (with `C-h f clone-indirect-buffer`), you will see that the second argument, which you have passed as `t` here, is described as follows:

> DISPLAY-FLAG non-nil means show the new buffer with ‘pop-to-buffer’.

and if you look at the doc string of `pop-to-buffer`, you will see:

> Display buffer specified by BUFFER-OR-NAME and **select its window.**

(emphasis added). IOW, `clone-indirect-buffer` already selects the window of the indirect buffer, so if you call `other-window` afterwards, you are actually selecting a *different* window, not that of the indirect buffer.